# Get lock on odbc operation

Tags: c#, odbc

is there a way to know that i cannot perform (for example) an update because the row is currently locked by another task?

I'm using a `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection` on *Adaptive Server Anywhere v9*, *.NET 4*